# send entire details through email

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to send student details to the company mail id .Here I have used grid view in that grid view it will display student details along with the check box. when I click particular row in the grid view, that  details send through SMTP

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select email from details", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                string email = rdr["email"].ToString();

                SendEmail(email);
            }
        }
    }
    private void SendEmail(string ToEmail)
    {
             string strEmail=string.Empty;
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("raj@gmail.com", ToEmail);
        StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("chk1");
                if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
                {
                    strEmail = ((Label)rw.FindControl("student Name")).Text;
                }
                sbEmailBody.Append(strEmail);
                    sbEmailBody.Append("");
                    sbEmailBody.Append("hello");
                    sbEmailBody.Append("<br/><br/>");
                    sbEmailBody.Append("<b>Testing Mail</b>");
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
                    mailMessage.Subject = "testing";
                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
                    {
                        UserName = "raj@gmail.com",
                        Password = "1234"
                    };

                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                }
            }

    catch
        {

        }
        }

         }

}
```

here I am not able to send details of the student from grid view

Comment: what error/issue are you facing?

Comment: Not able to send the student details  which is in the grid view through SMTP

Comment: you only need to get checked student details to be mailed?

Comment: yes i need checked students to be mailed

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using SSL, try change the port of `SmtpClient` to 465.

[Google SMTP Configurations](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600)